# iTunes Connect "Processing" binary indefinitely

Tags: app-store-connect

I recently submitted an app for review and then an emergency change request came in. Generally this is as simple as rejecting the previous binary and submitting a new build. I submitted a new build and went to reject the previously "Waiting for review" build although that build is staying in a "Processing" state while iTunes Connect shows the app in "Waiting for review" state. I submitted a 3rd build and it too changed to Active without issues.

Has anyone come across this issue and if so, how did you resolve it without leave the app in review? I have contacted iTunes Connect and was hoping to resolve the issue prior to the "waiting game".

*EDIT

**FYI for other users. If you submit a new build and assign that build to your app update while in the processing state, ie. before the build changes to the "Active" state, save, then upload a newer binary of the same version it will put the 1st binary into a "purgatory" like state of "Processing". I just tested this on another iTunes account and the same behavior happened. Long story short, wait for the binary to change to an "Active" state before assigning the binary to the update and saving.**

Comment: With recent changes made to iTunes connect website and the way it has been working recently, i am not surprised.

Comment: I also had some strange behaviours on itunes connect so far. it would be best to wait support person on Apple will solve it.

Comment: I agree on the recent changes comment. Overall I like the layout but I have found some "bugs" apparently. Thanks for the responses.